# SQL Statement for removing letters from column values after special character

Tags: t-sql

I have a Table named "TableA" and there is column " KNumber" and that column has some values [Data] which contain Pipe ' | ' in.

For example as below.

```
1. AMERIK20121218|HA

2. AMERIKINITIAL20121130|DSS

3. |DSS

4. |HI
```

Now I want to perform clean up on that "TableA" by removing these extra values in KNumber column- If there is an ' | ' at

the end and any value after ' | ', that need to be removed.

What would be the TSQL query to perform this operation? 
I have like 3000 rows for that column which have ' | ' in it. I want to update all these 3000 rows and remove whatever it is after that '|'.

I use SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Tried some query with CharIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `KNumber` is in a [full text index](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/), you may use:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET KNumber = SUBSTRING(KNumber,0,CHARINDEX('|', KNumber)-1)
WHERE Contains(KNumber, '|')
```

If it's not, you may use:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET KNumber = SUBSTRING(KNumber,0,CHARINDEX('|', KNumber)-1)
WHERE KNumber LIKE '%|%'
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce224/2)'s a demo.

Comment: Thanks Alex for solution. By the way what is full text index? Sorry I'm not much familiar with this.

Comment: You are welcome. I've updated the answer with a link which explains the full text indexing.

Comment: Hi Alex, I was testing this query and i came across one problem. Looking at your example, it remove one character extra and it causing me lot of problems. E.g. We inserted " ('AMERIK20121218|HA') " Value I want ans as  "AMERIK20121218" but query gives result as "AMERIK2012121" so it removed one character. Can you please help me ?

Comment: UPDATE TableA
SET KNumber = SUBSTRING(KNumber,1,CHARINDEX('|', KNumber)-1)
WHERE KNumber LIKE '%|%'      =>>>> This will solve issue